# filtering in python for elastic search

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am trying to filter out the elastic search query to create a pandas dataframe. I have two columns "type" and "api" in the dataframe on which iam applying filter. When I am applying one column as condition it is working fine..:-

```
result_dict = es.search(index="logstash-2018.08.11-alias", 
              body={"from": 0, "size": 10000,"query": 
              {"term" : {"type":"vx_apache_json"}}})
```

But when i am applying multiple condition like below :-

```
result_dict = es.search(index="logstash-2018.08.11-alias", body={"from": 0, "size": 1000,"queries": [
        { "term" : {"type" :"vx_apache_json"}},
        { "term" : {"api" :"viv_signin.php"}}
      ]})
```

I am getting the below error :-

RequestError: RequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', 'Unknown key for a START_ARRAY in [queries].')

Can someone help me here like how i can put multiple filtering in elastic search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code:-

```
result_dict = es.search(index="logstash-2018.08.11-alias", body={"from": 0, "size": 1000,"query": {
        "constant_score" : {
            "filter" : {
                 "bool" : {
                    "must" : [
                        { "term" : { "type" :"vx_apache_json" } }, 
                        {"term"  :{ "api" :"viv_signin.php" }}
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
)
```

And in the same way keep adding your filters.